# Android display offset/change position

Tags: android, shell, adb, resolution, display

Is it possible to offset the entire display content / change its position using adb shell?

As i recently noticed it is possible to change the resolution .

```
adb shell wm size <Res>.
```

So , i was wondering if it's possible to introduce an offset or change the display position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the wm command usage:

```
usage: wm [subcommand] [options]
       wm size [reset|WxH|WdpxHdp]
       wm density [reset|DENSITY]
       wm overscan [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM]
       wm scaling [off|auto]
       wm screen-capture [userId] [true|false]

wm size: return or override display size.
         width and height in pixels unless suffixed with 'dp'.

wm density: override display density.

wm overscan: set overscan area for display.

wm scaling: set display scaling mode.

wm screen-capture: enable/disable screen capture.

wm dismiss-keyguard: dismiss the keyguard, prompting the user for auth if necessary.
```

So the command you're looking for is `wm overscan` to offset the display:

`adb shell wm overscan a,b,c,d`

**Before Android 4.3:**

`adb shell am display-size`

ref: https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG and https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/QhWQArNDfS3

Comment: `am` stands for `ActivityManager` and it won't be useful for such overscan settings. Before 4.3 there was no `wm` but you could use `adb shell am display-size` instead to change the screen resolution (ref: https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG and https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/QhWQArNDfS3)

Comment: @TheAnimatrix did it work with `adb shell am display-size`?

Comment: @SimonMarquis is there a way to shift the display in a direction? I tried the 'overscan' command, and it breaks a lot of apps (even after restart). So, I used the 'size' command to set the height 100px less. Unfortunately, it shrunk to the middle, and there are padding on the top as well as the bottom. But, all the apps are working well. Is there a way to shift the display upwards on y-axis 50px, so that all the extra padding is on the bottom (the bottom 100px of my screen does not respond to touch)? I can't find any comprehensive list of commands anywhere... :(